# First Page of React App Blank when deployed using github pages

Tags: reactjs

I deployed by first react app on github pages but everything is blank except the navigation bar. However, after clicking on the navigation bar everything seems to work fine.
 
I also I have a path to my home page so I was wondering what's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I think we need to see some code.  Are you using react router?

Comment: Yes I am and here is my github repo

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` to your `Router` component.  Like this:

```js
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

This tells react router to use the full URL of your repo as the '/' of your Routes.  I had the same problem you're having, and this solved it.

Comment: what exactly is the public_url here?

Comment: it is the root url that the app is running on.  in your case it would be your username.github.io/repo-name/.  Check out [this article](https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1).  I'm not a fan of how h'es using `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`, but he explains better what it is and why you'd need it